# Search Results from an array by search the keyword in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
Array ( 
    [4621] => Hall Enstein 
    [4622] => Function Areas 
    [4623] => Dining Areas 
    [4624] => Events 
    [4625] => Galleries 
    [4626] => Custom Pages 
    [4627] => News 
    [4629] => Promotions
);
```

How to get result like `[4622] => Function Areas` with the search keyword like `f` or `fu`. I use `array_intersect()` function for this requirment. But here I have to search with the keyword `"Function Areas"`, not `f` or `fu`. With `f` or `fu`, search result `[4622] => Function Areas` is not coming. If any one know it, please help me.
Thank you

Comment: learn to frame your question in proper format.there was no need to re-edit @billyonecan's edit.

Comment: bad formating of the question

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the array:

```
$output = array_filter($yourArray, function($v) { 
  return stristr($v, 'fu'); 
});
```

Would output:

```
array
  4622 => string 'Function Areas' (length=14)
```

Comment: Its fine. But 'fu' will be dynamic. Do I send another parametere with $v for fu.

Comment: `... function($needle) use ($haystack) { return stristr($haystack, $needle); });`

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function to search for a partial match within the array values. You need to define a function here is a handy one using the array_filter function mentioned by @billyonecan:

```
function array_match_string($haystack, $needle){
    return array_filter($haystack, function($value) use ($needle){
        return stripos($value, $needle) !== false; 
    });
}
```

You can than simply call the function with an array and a string to search for:

```
$result_array = array_match_string($array, 'fu');
```

**Solution with PHP < 5.3** (we need a global helper variable to be visible in the callback):

```
function array_match_string_pre_php_53($haystack, $needle){
    global $_array_match_string_needle;
    $_array_match_string_needle = $needle;
    return array_filter($haystack, 'array_match_string_callback');
}

function array_match_string_callback($value){
    global $_array_match_string_needle;
    return strpos($value, $_array_match_string_needle) !== false;
}

$result_array = array_match_string_pre_php_53($array, 'Fu');
```

Comment: @insanebits: didn't needed the "by reference" but the use keyword is the actual trick ;)

Comment: When I came from C++ background by reference makes sense for me :)

Comment: Yes, but not in this case, as we don't have to change the value of $needle from within the anonymous function. Though it doesn't hurt to pass it by reference ;)

Comment: In c++ passing by reference means there is no copying so it would use less memory and work faster, thats why it makes sence.

Comment: That's a good point! Although the memory footprint of the needle shouldn't be that much, just can pass it by reference in this case, if you prefer to.

Comment: But it displays parse error like that Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION. How to manage it, I can't understand it in php.

Comment: Which Version of PHP are you using? I guess you'll need at least version 5.3 using the anonymous function. But you can also define the function with a name and than use this name in the array_filter call.

Comment: I have added a PHP < 5.3 solution. This isn't as nice as the one for PHP >= 5.3 but it should do exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching with strpos which returns position of found given keyword and -1 if string does not contain keyword

```
$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');

$found = array(); // every that matches keyword

$keyword = "e"; //searching for letter e

foreach($array as $fruit)
{
    if(stripos($fruit, $keyword) !== -1)
    {
        array_push($found, $fruit);
    }
}

// fruits should now contain apple and orange
```

Note that code wasn't tested so it can contain syntax errors but principle should work

Answer (score 0):

This requirement's another way is that this array will have to be moved in a loop where the array is in loop.
 `$keyword = strtolower(trim($needle));
                   foreach($array as $key=>$arrayvalue)
                   {
             $isExists = @preg_match("/$keyword/", $arrayvalue); 
             if($isExists)
              { $com = sprintf('%s [nid: %d]', ucwords($arrayvalue), $key);
            $spresults[$com] = ucwords($arrayvalue);
                      }
                   }`